# Как убрать отступ после формы?

Tags: html, php

Доброго всем времени суток.

```
<?
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>
    <form action=\"mail.php\" method=\"post\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidden1\" value=\"mail\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidden2\" value=\"123\">
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"text\" value=\"\" maxlength=\"7\">
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\" \">
    </form>
    </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Собственно имеем конструкцию. В браузере опера - отображается так, как в принципе и должно отображаться. В ie, ff, gc, as - отображается с отступом. Чтобы понять, это, как говориться, нужно увидеть. Подскажите, как этот отступ убрать?

Comment: @mixalef так вопрос решён?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите **echo**! Вы выводите при помощи PHP статический HTML, а потому PHP здесь совсем не нужен:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
    <form action="mail.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="mail">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden2" value="123">
    <input type="text" name="text" value="" maxlength="7">
    <input type="submit" value=" ">
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Eсho** имеет смысл использовать **только для вывода меняющихся данных**. Вставляйте PHP в HTML так:

```
<p><?php echo $smth; ?></p>
```

После чистки кода отступ исчез?

Comment: нет. но оказывается, нужно было просто прописать стиль

<form action=\"mail.php\" method=\"post\" style=\"margin: 0px; padding: 0px\">

Comment: Тогда сделайте сброс CSS: http://habrahabr.ru/post/45296/

Comment: @Khvorostin, а почему вы решили, что данная смесь вида "таблица+форма" не может быть динамичной, т.е динамически обновляемой?

Comment: @Asen, приведите пример того, как динамически меняются html-теги. Собственно, соль претензии в разнице между <?php echo '<p>' . $smth . '</p>'; ?> и <p><?php echo $smth; ?></p>

Comment: @Khvorostin - про сброс CSS, спасибо, не знал. про форму - есть еще одно, тоже интересное решение, господа - все запоминайте 8-) :

    <form action=\"mail.php\" method=\"post\" style=\"display: inline;\">

Answer (score 1):

Нужно форме сделать

```
style="display: block;"
```

или

```
 style="display: inline-block;"
```

Довно хотел это скззать но думал раз вы решили проблему сами не стал, ладно если кому надо ответил